# Conditional Formatting Cells c#

Tags: c#, gridview, formatting

How would i apply a format to this grid, i want to format the cells in the grid view if status = saved, i want this text to be displayed in red, so it is more noticeable

```
// setup columns
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 0).Text = "ID";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 1).Text = "Scrap Code";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 2).Text = "Station";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 3).Text = "Operator";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 4).Text = "Product";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 5).Text = "Status";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 6).Text = "Date Logged";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 7).Text = "Die";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 8).Text = "Core Print";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 9).Text = "Stamp";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 10).Text = "Line";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 11).Text = "Grid Ref";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 12).Text = "Cast Date";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 13).Text = "Shift";
            this.grid1.Cell(0, 14).Text = "Cast Hour";

            this.grid1.Column(14).Alignment = FlexCell.AlignmentEnum.CenterCenter;

    for (int i=0; i<arrData.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] theData = arrData[i].ToString().Split('\t');

                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 0).Text = theData[0];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 1).Text = theData[5];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 2).Text = theData[1];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 3).Text = theData[2];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 4).Text = theData[11];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 5).Text = theData[3];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 6).Text = theData[4].Replace("T", " "); ;
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 7).Text = theData[6];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 8).Text = theData[12];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 9).Text = theData[13];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 10).Text = theData[14];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 11).Text = theData[7];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 12).Text = theData[16].Replace("T", " "); ;
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 13).Text = theData[15];
                this.grid1.Cell(i + 1, 14).Text = theData[17];
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont u try this

```
           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string RowType = row.Cells[cellnumberofstatus].Value.ToString();

                if (RowType == "saved")
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try this

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string RowType = row.Cells[cellnumberofstatus].Value.ToString();

            if (RowType == "saved")
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
         }
```

Edit: try this

```
  if(dataGridView1.Rows[h].Cells[number].Value == "saved")
         dataGridView1.Rows[h].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Im getting the following error, 


"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: No im still getting same the error, the error is with the foreach aspect of the statement not the "if" part..

Comment: dont use foreach , just use the if condition(Edited one) . just show me the part which u getting error

Comment: do we need the .Row.Cells ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36715/discussion-between-kavithai-kannan-and-christopher-mcconville)